# Can someone Hack my phone personal data using my IP address?

Tags: ip

There is "My wifi router" Installed in one of my office PC's. I once connected my nokia lumia 925 to it. That software  "my wifi router" Shows our IP when we get connected. Is there any possibility then any person can hack my phone personal data using my IP address?

Answer (score 2):

On the mobile side, unless you specifically asked your provider for it, IPs are ***normally*** private (NATed) which makes it quite difficult to reach from outside that network.

With the wifi connection, again your connection gets NATed by your router, making the device unreachable directly too.

Finally note that an IP address is a publicly available information and not an attack vector by itself.

Answer (score 1):

An IP alone is not enough for hacking your phone. And while it doesn't slow an attacker down, the same time it does absolutely nothing to help attacking you.

IP addresses are no secrets, quite the opposite. It's just necessary for any (internet) connection to work. And even if this particular software wouldn't show the address, there are plenty opportuninties to get your IP.

Just don't worry about it.